# XML validation with PHP and XSD Error

Tags: php, xml, xsd, libxml2

I dont speak english, so forgive me.
I'm trying validate an xml file with your xsd using PHP, but dont work!

First I call `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` for get the errors.

Then I call `$xmlDomDocument->schemaValidate($pathFileXSD)` that returns `false`. So I get the errors with `libxml_get_errors()` function.

The message error says:

```
Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element', attribute 'type': References from this schema to components in the namespace 'http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws/shema/nfse_v01.xsd' are not allowed, since not indicated by an import statement. in file:///C:/v_59/httpdocs/arquivos_imobiliaria/betha/nfse_v01.xsd on line 273
```

I Dont understand the message error, is an error on the XSD file? But this isn't possible because the XSD is a part of an webservice. I appreciate any help. Sorry for the english.

I use PHP 5.3.1 and libxml2.7.6

Answer (score 0):

> Is an error on the XSD file?

Yes and No. The code `$xmlDomDocument->schemaValidate($pathFileXSD);` has a problem to actually load that file. That is all. It must not mean that the xsd file generally has an error, just that the PHP library can not load it without errors.

> But this isn't possible because the XSD is a part of an webservice.

As you can see, the XSD file of that webservice is not compatible with the DOMDocument library in PHP. Take the error message and contact the technical support of the webservice and discuss the issue with them.